# liftM null id return bool, but bool is not monad

Tags: haskell, types, monads

`Bool` type is not `Monad`

```
ghci> :t liftM
liftM :: Monad m => (a1 -> r) -> m a1 -> m r
```

Yet the following still returns `Bool`

```
ghci> :t (liftM null id)
(liftM null id) :: Foldable t => t a -> Bool
```

Answer (score 1):

```
null :: Foldable t => t a -> Bool
```

Therefore unification gives

```
liftM null :: (Monad m, Foldable t) => m (t a) -> m Bool
```

Then `liftM null id` must unify `id`, which is of type `b -> b`, with `m (t a)` where `m` is a `Monad` and `t` is a `Foldable`.  As it happens, the type `((->) r)` is [defined as a Monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-638).  So that means that the type of `id` can be written as `m b` where `m` is `((->) b)`.

```
id :: b -> b
id :: ((->) b) b   -- this is the same as above
-- m = ((->) b)
```

Now, `b` can be specialized to `t a` so that we get the desired type:

```
id :: ((->) (t a)) (t a)
-- m = ((->) (t a))
```

So back to `liftM null`, we have:

```
liftM null :: Foldable t => ((->) (t a)) (t a) -> ((->) (t a)) Bool
```

Or, to write it back in the usual infix `->` form,

```
liftM null :: Foldable t => (t a -> t a) -> t a -> Bool
```

The rest is clear -- we apply the above function to `id` to get

```
liftM null id :: Foldable t => t a -> Bool
```